# If $ f (x) - f (y) $ is an integrable function then $ f $ is integrable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ f: [0, 1] \rightarrow [−\infty, \infty] $ be a finite and measurable function a.e. If $ f (x) - f (y) $ is an integrable function then $ f $ is integrable.

I'm trying to do this exercise showing that it is non-negative and measurable. However, this path has been cumbersome. I would like to know if there is a shorter or simplified way to do this exercise. I'm not sure if this feature is actually positive. Some help is considered.
I think it could be proved using Fubini's theorem but I don't have good ideas for this yet

Comment: The answer will depend on the type of integrability you're looking for.

For instance, Lebesgue's Theorem says a function is *Riemann* integrable iff it has discontinuities of measure zero. In that case, your result follows quite easily. Which makes me think you must actually be looking for Lebesgue integrability?

Comment: oh! interesting observation, thought to answer in another way, can you illustrate this in the answer?

Comment: @dbx Exactly I'm looking for the integrability of Lebesgue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a $y$ such that $|f(y)|<\infty,$ and let $h_y(x)=f(x)-f(y)$.
Now note that $$\int |f(x)|dx\le \int |h_y(x)|dx +\int |f(y)|dx.$$

The first term is finite becase $h_y$ is integrable, and the second term is finite because $f(y)$ is a constant and the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$ is finite.